# Save terminal output to variable in expect/tcl

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Hej all,
I have to use an interactive program and I want to automatize it with expect. My experiences in Linux and scripting is not the best. So this is the program output:

```
enter minimum cross-correlation threshold: 0.15
enter the range and azimuth error thresholds: 1.6 1.0

range, azimuth error thresholds: 1.60000     1.00000
cross-correlation threshold: 0.15000
*
*
*
model fit std. dev. (samples) range: 0.5298   azimuth: 0.4166
set new error bounds? (0: no, 1: yes): 0
```

The first two lines and the last one are interactive. So with expect and send it was not a problem to enter the thresholds for one time. But I want to iterate this process. Therefore I have to save the results "range: 0.5298   azimuth: 0.4166" into two variables and then run again until I get good results e.g. "range: 0.02   azimuth: 0.02".

Anyone have an idea how I can store the results, compare them, and iterate the process?

That works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./offset_fitm_exp
expect "enter minimum cross-correlation threshold:" { send "0.15\r" }
expect "enter the range and azimuth error thresholds:" { send "1.6 1.0\r" }
expect "set new error bounds? (0: no, 1: yes):" { send "0\r" }
interact
```

Thanks for your help!
Bjoern

Comment: Can you add what you have already? The answer will probably need to be integrated deeply with it.

Comment: is the zero after the "):" a default output, or did you put that in?

Comment: I added the code now. I put it in

Comment: wait... are you hitting enter at each one of those lines? I thought that was program output.  one potential problem i see is that ":" is used in places besides the prompt.

Comment: No, not at each line. I only hit enter after I put the values in (lines 1,2 and 10)

Comment: Do you have source code for the program? (thinking that might be significantly easier to make the automation happen)

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: This question is more relevant for [so], not askubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate the iteration, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./offset_fitm_exp

set range   1.6
set azimuth 1.0

while {true} {
    expect "enter minimum cross-correlation threshold:"
    send "0.15\r" 

    expect "enter the range and azimuth error thresholds:" 
    send "$range $azimuth\r"

    expect -re {range: ([0-9.]+)   azimuth: ([0-9.]+} {
        set range   $expect_out(1,string)
        set azimuth $expect_out(2,string)
    }

    expect "set new error bounds? (0: no, 1: yes):" { 
        if {$range > 0.02 || $azimuth > 0.02} {
            send "1\r"
        } else {
            send "0\r" 
            break
        }
    }
}

interact
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Im thinking but I could get busy and forget, or side tracked.
so You can try processing the lines of output as lines that have fixed columns
(hopefully that is the case)
to match, and set output, you could do:

```
set A1 [lrange $expect_out(1,string) 2]
set A2 [lrange $expect_out(1,string) 3]
```

then do something like:

```
if {$A1>=N || $A2>=N} do something (like change the set a1,a2 values, or ....
```

Ill check back later.